# IE Automation - How to Trap 'NewProcess' event

Tags: internet-explorer, com, automation

In

Environment - Standard User, Win7x64, IE8 on opening

Unprotected URL, IE 8 will first start a tab with low integrity and the swap out this tab with another tab of medium integrity.

This is done behind the scene and the original IWebBrowser2 pointer is lost.

---

I want to catch the 'NewProcess' Event which will get generated during this swap out, please help me how to go about this.

Sample code can help me, me using C++

Ref - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/03/internet-explorer-automation-protected-mode-lcie-default-integrity-level-medium.aspx

Thank You

Comment: What is your objective: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I am losing the track of pointer to IWebBrowser2, my doing this I intend to get the correct IWebBrowser2 ptr for the newly opened medium integrity tab and continue my custom IE Automation

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trap this and other events using EventSink available in Windows API